# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python

I am using tenserflow first time with Python 2.7 . I am following tenserflow tutorial and when I am running the below line features

```
[tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
```

its throwing the error

> "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contrib'". Please help.

Comment: Did you name a file `tf.py`?

Comment: nope. name was different.

Answer (score 0):

However, it got solved after reinstalling the protofub.